# Django 1.6 format datetime in views

Tags: python, django, datetime

I've a booking form in my template that sends an email when it's submitted. In my database the datetime field is shown like: `Oct. 6, 2015, 3:58 p.m.` But when I get the email the datetime field is shown like: `2015-10-06 15:58:50.954102` How do i format it such that in the email it's shown exactly like how it's shown in the database?

## models.py

```
class Booking(models.Model):
    patient_name = models.CharField(max_length=1300)
    phone = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank = True)
    preference = models.CharField(max_length=150,null = True, blank = True) #morning,noon,night
    doctor = models.ForeignKey(Doctor)
    clinic = models.ForeignKey(Clinic,null=True, blank = True)
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=True, blank = True, null = True)


    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%s %s" % (self.patient_name, self.doctor)
```

## views.py

```
 lead = Booking(doctor_id=doctor.id, clinic_id=doctor.clinic.id, preference=preference, patient_name=patient_name, phone=phone)
 lead.save()
 body = "Request Made: " + str(lead.datetime) +" "
 email = EmailMessage('Blah', body, to=[clinic.email])
 email.send()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can format datestrings using [`strftime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime)

```
>>> from datetime import date
>>> dt = date(2015, 10, 6, 15, 58, 50)
>>> dt.strftime("%b. %-d %Y %-I:%M %p")
'Oct. 6 2015 2:12 PM'
```

There's a list of the codes for `strftime` at at http://strftime.org/

So in your view you would do something like

```
body = "Request Made: %s " % lead.datetime.strftime("%b. %-d %Y %-I:%M %p")
```

Answer (score 2):

Thats not exactly how it's in the database, it's just what the tool you use to view inside the database, displays datetime.

However if you want your datetime to look exactly like that, use:

```
lead.datetime.strftime("%b. %-d %Y %-I:%M %p")
```

Here are some relevant sources:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime
https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior